# How can I assign different animation-speeds to different properties in a CSS3 animation?

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to make a ship moves from left to right and from  top to bottom at the same time (it describes a straight downward line). I want to assign different speeds to the animation in the 'X' and 'Y' axis. I mean I want little ship to move slower when moving from left to right, and faster when moving from top to bottom, but I haven't been able to accomplish this because I don't know how to separate the speed of the different animated properties. I would highly appreciate any suggestion. Here is my code:

```css
body {
        overflow-x:hidden;  
    }
    
    div {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      top: 20px;
      background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c2/bb/ae/c2bbaed0207deef5775af9c01e1b31ba.jpg');
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      animation: mymove 5s linear infinite;
    
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
      0% {
        left:-1%;
        top:-1%;
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      
      20% {
        
        transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      40%
       {
       
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      60% {
        
        transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      80%{
        
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      100% {
        left:100%;
        top:100%;
        transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated keyframe

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
      0% {
        left:-1%;
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }

      20% {

        transform: rotate(-5deg)
      }
      40%
       {
       left:90%;
        transform: rotate(5deg)
      }
      60% {

        transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0px,0px)
      }
      80%{

        transform: rotate(95deg) translate(210px,0px)
      }
      100% {
        left:90%;
        transform: rotate(90deg) translate(410px,0px)
      }
    }
```

**Updated answer#1**
ship will travel diagonally

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
        0% {

            transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(55deg)
        }
        10% {
            transform: translate(100px,50px) rotate(60deg)
        }
        20% {
            transform: translate(200px,100px) rotate(55deg)
        }
        30% {
            transform: translate(300px,150px) rotate(60deg)
        }
        40% {
            transform: translate(400px,200px) rotate(55deg)
        }
        50% {
            transform: translate(500px,250px) rotate(60deg)
        }
        60% {
            transform: translate(600px,300px) rotate(55deg)
        }
        70% {
            transform: translate(700px,350px) rotate(60deg)
        }
        80% {
            transform: translate(800px,400px) rotate(55deg)
        }
        90% {
            transform: translate(900px,450px) rotate(60deg)
        }
        100% {
            transform: translate(1000px,500px) rotate(55deg)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that update makes the little ship describes a "L" trajectory. I want the little ship to keep moving in a diagonal downward line: from top to bottom and left to right. I mean, starting at left:0 and top:0 and ending in left:100% and top:100% . But translating slower in the "X" axis than in the "Y" axis. Hope someone can help me. :)